# How to use Kumo Java Word Cloud?

Tags: java, github, word-cloud

I am an amateur in Java and I don't know how to use the Kumo wordcloud.

I downloaded the source from GitHub

How to import it into the project from its source?
How to try out the examples?

Using Eclipse IDE (Mars) with JDK 1.8

https://github.com/kennycason/kumo

Comment: Hi. I think you should improve your question : what is your environment/IDE ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, edited the question

Answer (score 3):

In general I'd recommend using maven for importing libraries. If your project is a Maven project you can simply add the Kumo dependency via:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kennycason</groupId>
    <artifactId>kumo-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

In the case that you are wanting to edit or extend Kumo, ping me on GitHub and let me know what you need. You can also fork the project, make edits and then submit them for PR and help make Kumo better.

Also, thanks for using Kumo!